# SVN : missing files in local copy

Tags: eclipse, svn

I use Eclipse Subversion client to checkout my project from a svn repository.
My coworkers has committed 2 new files which i can see on the svn remote repository but I can't get them when i update from the head.
The 2 files are in the trunk, like me.
 
Someone have an idea ?

Comment: What kind of files are they? Are they in a subdirectory? What does it say when you try to update?

Comment: For a start, what does "svn status -u" say about these files?

Comment: Do these files have a path longer than 255 characters? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802727/svn-255-character-problem

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you have a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)? Then you could try do to an explicit update to the files:

```
svn update path/to/missing/file.txt
```

Comment: I am using this as well, since I have a very sparse checkout. But I want a way to get ALL the missing files... still searching.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it refuses to download it, it's because prior to deletion there were merge conflicts. Even though the file is gone, the merge conflicts remain, and this stops it from restoring the file :S

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I had a similar problem.

This is what I did.  Check with

```
svn ls
```

and compare to

```
ls -1
```

Then

```
svn ls | xargs svn up
```

To do this recursively just add -R

```
svn ls -R | xargs svn up
```

Note that this will take a while if you have a big code base

Comment: Great answer! As an aside, I am saddened that eclipse subversion cannot be trusted to keep svn in-sync. I mean, a simple svn ls uncovers the issue -- what terrible things is this eclipse software doing such that it misses svn files in a project that simple command line instructions can uncover?

Answer (score 1):

You can also explicitly update to a revision using '-r' and then the current revision number:

```
svn update -r 1234 path/to/missing/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the HEAD and set the recursive options to full in the Eclispe Team menu. And now it works :-) Curious I was on the head before.