# SVN 255 Character Problem

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, char, character

I am using TortiseSVN and we have a problem when we exporting etc because subversion errors. The path has a character limit 255 - so I am not sure if this is the problem [I think it is in Win7 x-64 bit]

How do I fix this ? i.e. allow paths for >255 characters ?

Comment: Please post the error messages

Comment: hi :) it just says "TortiseSVN - The system cannot find the path specified" - but the file exists and indeed is used inside the project.

Comment: In my line of work we run into this all the time, especially with auto-generated paths. You just have to re-engineer your directory structure and, if possible, shorten some names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Windows limitation, not a tortoise limitation.

[Has Windows 7 Fixed the 255 Character File Path Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065993/has-windows-7-fixed-the-255-character-file-path-limit)

Comment: oh wow thx. didnt realise it was a windows limit. god that sucks.

Comment: Yeah, it blows. No simple way around it in most scenarios. May want to accept the answer, if it answered your question.

Comment: I also came across this limit when I noticed that the Tortoise SVN "Add" file menu item was not appearing on some files (those where the full length of the path and filename was > 255), that needed to be added. Well it beats 8.3 from the late 90's.. but still frustrating

Answer (score 3):

Subversion works quite well with paths longer than MAX_PATH (256 chars), but you must provide absolute paths for every command, not relative ones.
TortoiseSVN already does this, but there's another limitation: the Windows Explorer can not deal with such long paths, even though NTFS can. So you can checkout/update/commit in TortoiseSVN such paths, but you can't access those anymore in Explorer.

To 'shorten' such paths, you can use the [SUBST](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true) command.